# Add custom group to Home tab in Outlook 2010 using VBA

Tags: vba, ribbon, ribbon-control, outlook-2010

Can't seem to find any simple VBA tutorials for adding a custom group to the Home tab in the Outlook 2010 ribbon.

Shouldn't it be a couple of simple steps involving something like traversing objects in the Home tab and programmatically add the group with controls etc, or redefine the XML that describes the Home tab.

Is there any sample VBA code or articles that have this simple example? Specifically I'm trying to add a custom group with 1 text field and 1 button that fires a custom macro.

Cheers,
Dave
--Trindaz on Fedang #outlook-2010-vba

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(office.12).aspx#OfficeCustomizingRibbonUIforDevelopers_WhatAbout says "In the case of Outlook, only COM add-ins can customize the Fluent UI." Maybe VBA just *isn't* an option for customizing Outlook 2010 ribbon?

Answer (score 7):

I wasn't able to get any VBA working for this, but I was able to...

1. Create a new Outlook 2007 project type in Visual Studio 2008
2. Add a new Ribbon (XML) item to the project
3. Follow the instructions in the sample code in the newly created Ribbon1.vb
4. Make sure the `<tab>` element in Ribbon1.xml has property `idMso="TabMail"`
5. Publish and run the installer application to get the new items appearing in the Home tab of the Outlook ribbon

Done!

Comment: I've been looking everywhere for this info, cheers. Why oh Why is a tab labelled "Home" in Outlook called "TabMail" in COM??!?!

Comment: LOL - why are Excel data tables called ListObjects under the covers ? silly MS :)

Comment: This makes me really want to get Visual Studio (I was trying to do this too, and also failing with VBA).

Answer (score 3):

Another answer using Ribbon XML for Outlook 2010:

```
 <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabMail">
        <group id="Group0"  label="my Group" insertBeforeMso="GroupMoveActions">
          <button id="myButton"
              size="large"
              label="someLabel"
              screentip="A tip to read..."
              supertip="Some super tip..."
              />
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

You can also download this file: [Office 2010 Help Files](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627) which contains the IDs of the Outlook controls. Once installed, look for the file **OutlookExplorerControls.xlsx**, this file contains the names of the groups you can use for the property *insertBeforeMso*.